# Django Retrive data after a specific number or index

Tags: django, django-views

i have two rendered contexts in my view:

```
def PostHomeView(request):
RecentPost = Post.objects.order_by("-date").all()[:5]
AllOtherPosts = Post.objects.order_by("-date").all()
template_name = 'lista_post.html'
context = {**strong text**
    'recentposts' : RecentPost,
    'allposts' : AllOtherPosts
}
return render(request,template_name,context)
```

in the second one ('allposts') i would like to get all objcects without the first fve
how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slicing as **`AllOtherPosts = Post.objects.order_by("-date").all()[5:]`**